# Google Webmaster Tools robots test not working

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

Within Webmaster Tools I have supplied my test content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:/admin/
Disallow: /tag/
```

When I specify the URL to test against, for example:

```
http://www.site.com/tag/
```

It gives me this result:

"Allowed: Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions"

As far as I know I have set this up correctly, shouldn't Google be saying that the `/tag/` directory is "disallowed"?

Comment: Have you set up the exact same host in GWT? (e.g. with resp. without `www.`?)

Answer (score 1):

If you've *just* updated your robots.txt file then Google may not have re-read it yet. Give it some time to get re-crawled. Do make sure you have a newline between `User-agent: *` and `Disallow:/admin/`.

You could also ask Google to permanently remove specific directories using the [URL Removal Tool](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663427). From Google's help page:

1. On the Webmaster Tools home page, click the site you want.
2. On the left-hand menu, click **Optimization** and then click **Remove URLs**.
3. Click **New removal request**.
4. Type the URL of the directory you want removed from search results
   and then click **Continue**. (The URL is case-sensitive)
5. Click **Remove directory**.
6. Click **Submit Request**.

Also take a look at [when not to use the URL Removal Tool](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1269119).

Answer (score 0):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/ 
Disallow: /tag/
```

Try this, it must work.